# Migrating to SharePoint 2010

Tags: migration

We have a publishing site with some custom webparts but I'm not really concerned about those as I can probably recompile and redeploy them. Having said that, I'm trying the "database attach" method. I was following a word document titled SharePoint 2010 Cookbook: How to Migrate a SharePoint 2007 site to SharePoint 2010 Using Database Attach".

It describes three steps in which the first step rather redundant: "Move the site to a new web application in SharePoint 2007". So if there is a hidden magic in the step that I don't see please explain, as I skipped this part.

Step two instructs to "Copy a content database backup to the SP2010 SQL Server". What we have is a 64 bit Win 2008 running a SQL 2008 R2.

Next I had created a web application and blank site collection. For convenience I've renamed the database to match it with "migrating" database.

After all that, I've restored the 'migrating" database over the database on the SP2010 SQL server.

Needless to say it did not work. The browser has a plain black on white error: "500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR". In the manage database upgrade status of the Central Administration the said database status is "not responding". SQL server is running; service account is a domain level account with full admin rights; both servers on the same domain.
Have you any ideas as to how to make this work?

Thanks,
Risho

Answer (score 1):

What you'll want to do is take the 2007 database, restore it to your SQL 2008 R2 server. Don't rename it to match anything.

Create a new web application, one that is empty, free of other site collections. You can backup/restore the site collection later to move it around.

Use PowerShell to Mount-SPContentDatabase to add the content database to your web app. At this point, it'll perform the upgrade.

Once it's done, your site in the database will be located at the same location it was before. For example, if the site collection was in domain.com/sites/HR, then in your new site it would be in domain2.com/sites/HR.

That should do it, like I said before, if you want to move it into another web app, use the backup-spsite and restore-spsite to move it around as needed.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your help David, but it didn't not work. Created the web app without the site collection. Then I "mounted" the database as you suggested. The PowerShell had spit out and ID - a long guid; Name: WSS_Content_XXX_Home.bak - which was the backup of the database from MOSS 2007; Server - the sql server; and CurrentSiteCount: 0 (Zero) - this concerns me.

Comment: When you mounted the database, did it show an upgrade process with a percentage? Sorry, I forget the exact syntax. The GUID that was spit out, what was it's label? It should have been above the GUID.

Comment: I don't recall seeing a progress percentage. This is what I typed in the PowerShell window: Mount-SPContentDatabase "WSS_Content_XXX_Home.bak -DatabaseServer "sql-022" -WebApplication https://sp-022

Comment: OOooo... yeah, that won't work, the database name value should be the name of the database as it sites in SQL. So after you restore the SQL database into SQL, use the name it shows in SQL Management Studio

Comment: I just realized we're conversing on my other post. You mentioned an "upgrade progress" when mounting the database. Does that mean that I did not use the correct syntax? Also the database name is what it was in MOSS 2007 less the ".bak" extension. So when it mounted the actual database name inclided the extension.